# I am getting an unknown file transfer error (Flashing TWRP)

Tags: twrp, fastboot

I am trying to flash twrp onto my unlocked Moto G4 Play so I can install a new version of Android but, I keep on getting this error. I have recently factory reset my phone and I am not sure if it is related.

```
C:\adb>fastboot flash recovery twrp.img
target reported max download size of 268435456 bytes
sending 'recovery' (8296 KB)...
FAILED (data transfer failure (Unknown error))
finished. total time: 5.013s
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try different usb ports. Try different usb cables. Update fastboot.exe. re-download another .img file and verify the md5.

Comment: I don't know if this is related but, it may be the .img. Whenever I right-click the file, my computer freezes, and the file explorer crashes. I cannot rename it.

Comment: If you suspect the .img file then delete it. Next go download a new .img file and verify the md5 that its good.

Comment: I've even downloaded an older version, same thing. I'll check if the MD5 is good.

Comment: Ok, the MD5 is good. Anything else?

Comment: I got a newer cord and it now works. I also disabled some services on my Win10 PC and that seemed to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FAILED (data transfer failure (Unknown error)) error can happen for a few reason. It happens when there is issues with communication transferring data. To trouble shoot the cause start by:

- Trying different usb ports
- Trying different usb cables
- Update fastboot.exe
- Download another .img file and verify the md5.
- Double check the Bootloader is unlock

Answer (score 0):

Regarding *only* the quality of USB cables, the **QooPow qualMeter** (http://www.qoopow.com/) allows you to check which of your USB (and Ethernet) cables are the best.

It might looks pricey, but it may save you lots of trial-and-error time and stress, especially if you routinely encounter cable quality-related issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running it from a computer with a AMD chipset, that might be your problem. I am having the same issues when I am trying to use fastboot or literally anything close to a android tool on my ryzen 5 5200 processor and it won't work. as soon as I tried using said tools on mac or a intel chipset, they work. smh